# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting '(' in

Tags: php

```
$command = $_POST['cmd'];
$args = $_POST['args'];

if($args == !empty && $command != 'reload'){

}
```

Thanks guys, got it working!

Comment: `$args == !empty` is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

empty is a function.

```
$command = $_POST['cmd'];
$args = $_POST['args'];
if(!empty($args) && $command != 'reload'){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty()` is construct and you should have to use it like:

```
if(!empty($args) && $command!='reload'){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if condition:

```
if(!empty($args) && $command != 'reload')
```